# Help outputting Drupal View JSON data using getJSON function

Tags: views

I'm trying to return the view data and display it in a list for verification.

It is sending for the data and seems to receive it (I get a 200), but it is not outputting the data.

Any help much appreciated!

```
<div id="ajax"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('/views/ajax?view_name=latest_new&view_display_id=page_1&view_args=city', function(data) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            items.push('<li id="' + i + '">' + item + '</li>');
        });

        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list',
            html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('#ajax');

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: is ajax switched on in settings of page_1 ?

Comment: It wasn't because I didn't want to use an Ajax pager for the view. I switched it on and I still get the same result. In the Firebug Console tab I can see the request and it returns a '200 OK' as well as data (I can view it on the Response & JSON sub-tabs of the Console tab) but I don't get anything outputted on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in my (current) solution.

My view outputs all nodes date descending. My secondary menu consists of taxonomy terms that can be passed to the view as arguments. The code below works for displaying nodes containing the specified taxonomy term.

It needs work, but so far so good.

```
$('#block-menu-secondary-links a').bind('click', function(){
    var arg = $(this).attr("title");
    $.get('views/ajax?view_name=latest_new&view_display_id=page_1&view_args='+arg, null, response);
    return false;
});

var response = function(data) {
    var result = Drupal.parseJson(data);
    $('#content').html(result.display);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
  url:'views/ajax',
  dataType: 'json',
  data:{
    view_name: 'my view name',
    view_display_id: 'default',
    view_args: 'view argument goes here',
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if(data[1].data !== undefined){
      // the view results will be in data[1].data
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Does that code work on Drupal 6 too?

Comment: it's jQuery so it should. Though I forget what version of jQuery Drupal 6 has. I think there is a module called 'jquery update' to update the jquery version easily in drupal 6.

Comment: I was wondering if the menu callback for views/ajax would accept parameters that are different between Drupal 6, and Drupal 7. Apparently, there isn't any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `/views/ajax`'s result is as you expect it to be. On Drupal 7, it returns an array of [Ajax Commands](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7), not the views results as an array of strings. See [`views_ajax()`](http://api.lullabot.com/views_ajax/7) (or [`views_ajax()`](http://api.lullabot.com/views_ajax) for Drupal 6).

If you want to retrieve the results of a views as a JSON array, it's probably easier to use the [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module.

After viewing the Firebug screenshot, there is no `items` properties on the `data`argument of the `$.getJSON`'s callback. Your `$.each(data.items, function(i, item) {...});` loops over an `undefined` value and does nothing. The response to your `$.getJSON` request contains a `display`property which seems to be the **rendered** results from the view. Again, I don't thing that the data your are looking for and you need something to get the results as structured JSON data.

Comment: Here are some screens of Firebug--

[link](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-PBTOFm1dGB8/TfflzmJ86xI/AAAAAAAAFc0/nFGneK6BKCU/s800/Screen%252520shot%2525202011-06-14%252520at%2525206.44.38%252520PM.png)

[link](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-eOGj5uzBTDQ/TfflzgP5SPI/AAAAAAAAFcw/wBK1YIj9dNE/s800/Screen%252520shot%2525202011-06-14%252520at%2525206.45.32%252520PM.png)

Thanks, I'll take a look at those links. It's a D6 install.

Comment: Ah, of course. How would I use the 'display' property? data.property?

Comment: I guess everybody has to start somewhere. You should really figure what technologies you are using and learn them before trying to do anything with it. For JavaScript and JSON, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide http://json.org/js.html. For Drupal, see http://drupal.org/getting-started, http://drupal.org/documentation/develop. For PHP, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php.

Comment: Thanks. I know PHP and JS/jQuery, but nothing advanced. I'm self taught so I may have missed some fundamentals. I guess I better get studying again.